# Cannot center-align items vertically in BottomNavigation

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to align items in the center vertically inside a bottom navigation in Compose. I'm not supplying any height to the modifiers. For some reason the items and the icons resist vertical center alignment. Here's what I have and then follows my code:

[image]

```
@Composable
fun BottomBarUi(backStackEntry: State<NavBackStackEntry?>, onNavigate: (String) -> Unit) {
    BottomNavigation(modifier = Modifier){
        val currDest = backStackEntry.value?.destination
        for (screen in LocalInfo.current.bottomBarItems){

            BottomNavigationItem(
                selected = currDest?.hierarchy?.any{it.route == screen.route} == true,
                onClick = {
                          onNavigate(screen.route)
                },
                icon = { Icon(painterResource(screen.iconId), contentDescription = screen.route, modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.CenterVertically))},
                label = { Utils.getRouteLabel(screen.route)},
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(1.dp)
                    .align(Alignment.CenterVertically)
                    .weight(1f)
            )
        }
    }

}

@Preview
@Composable
fun PreviewBottomBarUi() {
    BottomBarUi(backStackEntry = rememberNavController().currentBackStackEntryAsState(), onNavigate = {})
}
```

Comment: The items cannot be aligned to the bottom either.

Comment: It looks like your resources have an extra transparent padding. With `Icons.Default.Person` your code works fine. The easiest solution is to crop the drawables so that only the visible part of the image remains

Comment: Philip I'm using vector drawables from the IDE, sized 48dp x 48dp upon creation. Editing their files to have 48-sized viewPort width and height didn't not help.

Answer (score 1):

If your icons have padding and you don't want to remove them, you can offset all the icons in the BottomNavigation by setting the `offset` modifier. Also remove your `align` modifier:

```
BottomNavigationItem(
     selected = currDest?.hierarchy?.any{it.route == screen.route} == true,
     onClick = {
                  onNavigate(screen.route)
     },
     icon = { Icon(painterResource(screen.iconId), contentDescription = screen.route, modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.CenterVertically))},
     label = { Utils.getRouteLabel(screen.route)},
     modifier = Modifier
          .padding(1.dp)
          .offset(y = 10.dp)
          .weight(1f)
)
```

Another thing: it isn't clear why you are setting the label property since the image you've shown above doesn't display the image.